# Using self keyword in a class in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I know that "self" in Lua is similiar to "this" in Java.  "this" means current object in Java, but I know Java is object-oriented, while Lua is prototype-based.  Could anyone explain why the code below has to use "self.last" instead of "self" to access the current node of the linked list?  Thank you.  :)

```
list = {}
list.__index = list

setmetatable(list, { __call = function(_, ...)
local t = setmetatable({length = 0}, list)
  for _, v in ipairs{...} do t:push(v) end
  return t
end })

function list:push(t)
  if self.last then
    self.last._next = t
    t._prev = self.last
    self.last = t
  else
    self.first = t
    self.last = t
  end
  self.length = self.length + 1
end
```

Comment: `self` is not a keyword but a name like any other, even though the syntactic sugar for member-functions names the implicit parameter `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different kinds of objects in your program: list objects and nodes. The list object manages a chain of linked nodes and has the following fields:

```
listobject = {
  length = 0,   -- number of nodes managed by this list object
  first = nil,  -- reference to first node in this list; nil if list is empty
  last = nil    -- reference to last node in this list; nil if list is empty
}
```

The reference to the first node is useful for iterating and prepending to the list, while the `last` reference allows for efficient appending. List objects also have a metatable so that you can call methods on them:

```
listobject:push( {"node1"} )
```

Unless you do something funny, the `self` parameter of the `push` method will always be a list object, not a node.

Nodes on the other hand have references to the next and previous node in a chain:

```
node = {
  _next = nil,  -- might be nil if not in list or last node
  _prev = nil,  -- might be nil if not in list or first node
  -- plus some data
}
```

So in the `push` method you access `self.last` to check whether the list is empty (you could have checked `self.length` as well), and if it is not, to find the last node in the current list where you can append the new node passed as argument to `push`. When you have done so, the `last` (and `first`) references in the list object have to be updated, obviously. The list object (`self` in the body of the `push` method) is *not* part of the chain of nodes.

Comment: Thanks so much, siffiejoe

Comment: Thanks so much, siffiejoe~  l'd like to add that it is linked list data structure with lua table.  self.last is to  keep last node to  efficient append as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

`self` is used to access the previous argument called to the list.
For example, if you called `list({"Hello"}, {"world"}, {"my"}, {"name"}, {"is"})`, `list:push` would get called **five** times. One call for each argument.

If there is no **last** (this is `self.last`) argument specified (which is the case for the first argument), it will set `{"Hello"}` to `t = {"Hello"}; t.first = t; t.last = t;` (self referring tables).

If it's the second onwards, it tells the previous table (`{"Hello"}`) that the next table is `{"my"}`, tells `{"my"}` what the previous table is and also sets the current table in the whole "list" as last. Keep in mind that `list:push(t)` is called several times. This means that self.last is called many times but after the list has been instantiated only one table (the last argument) is in `self.last` and each table has a record of the next or previous table in the list.